# WakeLock finalized while still held

Tags: android, android-activity, wakelock

The `pm` and `keepScreenOn` variables are globally defined.

I grab the PowerManager.WakeLock in my OnCreate method:

```
pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
keepScreenOn = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_LOCK,"tpd");
```

in my onStart, onResume, and onRestart I grab the lock with

```
if (keepScreenOn == null) {
    keepScreenOn = pm.newakeLock(PowerManager,SCREEN_BRIGHT_LOCK,"tpd");
}
keepScreenOn.acquire();
```

in my onDestroy, onPause, and onStop I release the lock with:

```
if (keepScreenOn != null) {
  keepScreenOn.release();
  keepScreenOn = null
}
```

After my app exits I get a failure screen and adb complains that

> java.lang.Exception: WakeLock finalized while still held: tpd

Tracing shows that I released the lock before exit.
What have I missed?

There is no way out of the app without crossing at least one of
`onPause`, `onStop`, or `onDestroy`. I can see that the app called
`release()` as often as it called acquire() so even though the
wakelock is reference counted it should still have zero refs.

Comment: May be it is not related to your problem, but why you are creating and releasing lock in so many places? Why not to do it only at onResume and onPause?

Comment: I tried that. Then I traced every onXXX routine. Then I added it

Comment: Is your `keepScreenOn` variable is declared only once in a class? Is there some other declarations with lesser scope (i.e. declared in method).

Comment: I tend to use `WakeLock.acquire(5000)`, where 5,000 is a timeout, or another timeout that you wish. This method seemed to work consistently. Whereas `WakeLock.acquire()` without a timeout unexpectedly can lead to **WakeLock finalized while still held**. It's a hit-and-miss affair. If you don't want to write your own WakeLock implementation, take a look at CommonsWare's WakeLock [library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful/tree/master/wakeful). It's not bad.

Answer (score 32):

Ok I believe I found the problem.

The WakeLock is reference counted. That means that if a second `acquire()`
happens it will just bump the reference count. Every call to `acquire()`
needs to be protected by a call to `isHeld()` as in:

```
if ((keepScreenOn != null) &&           // we have a WakeLock
    (keepScreenOn.isHeld() == false)) {  // but we don't hold it 
  keepScreenOn.acquire();
}
```

I had assumed that `acquire()` on a lock I held did nothing so
multiple `acquire()` calls caused the problem. Since the reference
count is not zero the GC throws an error.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question is old, but keep in mind that WakeLocks are 'reference counted' by default. You can turn off reference counting using `setReferenceCounted(boolean)`, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html#setReferenceCounted(boolean)

Answer (score 0):

No, there is only one declaration at the global scope and all
calls to the acquire() and release() occur in that scope. I
println when they happen and the acquire() occurs once and the
release occurs once.